# Unable to get associated vpc from the hosted zones boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I am trying to get the associated vpc id from the hosted zone but the result set does not show anything indicating a vpc id. Need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember VPC ID is associated with a private zone only. You can get the VPC ID by using `get_hosted_zone`:

```
>>> r53.get_hosted_zone('Z5TB46T21X9X7E')['GetHostedZoneResponse']['VPCs']['VPC']['VPCId']
'vpc-abc12345'
```

Comment: Thank you. This suffice my purpose.

Comment: Sure :). There is one more thing. The above code returns only 1 vpc attached to the hosted private hosted zone where as we can attach multiple vpcs, is there any way to find out all the attached vpcs ?

Comment: I gave an example. To find all VPCs, just loop through `r53.get_hosted_zone('Z5TB46T21X9X7E')['GetHostedZoneResponse']['VPCs']`

Comment: I did but it returns only 1 vpc. {u'VPC': {u'VPCId': u'vpc-my-vpc-id, u'VPCRegion': u'us-east-1'}}

Comment: Or probably it will take time to reflect in the response of API cause i have just attached it few minutes before ?

Comment: Have tried with different combinations. But it only returns one vpc that too the last attached one. any suggestions ? @helloV

Comment: Checked the documentation. A hosted zone can have only one VPC id associated with it.

Comment: I see. Well, Thanks a lot. I appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: A private hosted zone can definitely have more than one associated VPC. The documentation is a little vague about that, but you can definitely associate more than one VPC.